# How to query a table populated with wait stats data

Tags: sql

I have a table that collects wait stats data every 5 minutes,

it has startdate and enddate columns with some other columns as well,

I need to query the table to give me some readings like 5 hours ago, 10 hours ago ..

I tried to select using between but gave me blank data

any tips please

Comment: post the query you did.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

If your table has some structure similar to this:

```
ts_start           |ts_end             |otherstuff
2017-01-14 20:00:01|2017-01-14 20:00:02|other stuff 01
2017-01-14 20:00:02|2017-01-14 20:00:03|other stuff 02
2017-01-14 20:00:03|2017-01-14 20:00:04|other stuff 03
2017-01-14 20:00:04|2017-01-14 20:00:05|other stuff 04
2017-01-14 20:00:05|2017-01-14 21:00:01|other stuff 05
2017-01-14 21:00:01|2017-01-14 21:00:02|other stuff 06
2017-01-14 21:00:02|2017-01-14 21:00:03|other stuff 07
2017-01-14 21:00:03|2017-01-14 21:00:04|other stuff 08
2017-01-14 21:00:04|2017-01-14 21:00:05|other stuff 09
2017-01-14 21:00:05|2017-01-14 22:00:01|other stuff 10
2017-01-14 22:00:01|2017-01-14 22:00:02|other stuff 11
2017-01-14 22:00:02|2017-01-14 22:00:03|other stuff 12
2017-01-14 22:00:03|2017-01-14 22:00:04|other stuff 13
2017-01-14 22:00:04|2017-01-14 22:00:05|other stuff 14
2017-01-14 22:00:05|9999-12-31 23:59:59|other stuff 15
```

... is this what you were looking for ? (I had to mimick CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, otherwise this won't work in a few hours, and I'm trying to fetch all occurrences that I found within an hour to get something relevant ...)

```
WITH foo (ts_start,ts_end,otherstuff) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 20:00:01',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 20:00:02','other stuff 01'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 20:00:02',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 20:00:03','other stuff 02'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 20:00:03',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 20:00:04','other stuff 03'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 20:00:04',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 20:00:05','other stuff 04'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 20:00:05',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 21:00:01','other stuff 05'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 21:00:01',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 21:00:02','other stuff 06'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 21:00:02',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 21:00:03','other stuff 07'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 21:00:03',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 21:00:04','other stuff 08'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 21:00:04',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 21:00:05','other stuff 09'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 21:00:05',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 22:00:01','other stuff 10'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 22:00:01',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 22:00:02','other stuff 11'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 22:00:02',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 22:00:03','other stuff 12'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 22:00:03',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 22:00:04','other stuff 13'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 22:00:04',TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 22:00:05','other stuff 14'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-14 22:00:05',TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 23:59:59','other stuff 15'
)
,   current_timestamp_mimick(current) AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-15 01:00:00' 
)
SELECT
  current AS "current_timestamp"
, *
FROM foo, current_timestamp_mimick
WHERE current - INTERVAL '3 HOURS' >= ts_start  
  AND current - INTERVAL '4 HOURS' <  ts_end    
;


current_timestamp         |ts_start                  |ts_end                    |otherstuff    |current
2017-01-15 01:00:00       |2017-01-14 20:00:05       |2017-01-14 21:00:01       |other stuff 05|2017-01-15 01:00:00
2017-01-15 01:00:00       |2017-01-14 21:00:01       |2017-01-14 21:00:02       |other stuff 06|2017-01-15 01:00:00
2017-01-15 01:00:00       |2017-01-14 21:00:02       |2017-01-14 21:00:03       |other stuff 07|2017-01-15 01:00:00
2017-01-15 01:00:00       |2017-01-14 21:00:03       |2017-01-14 21:00:04       |other stuff 08|2017-01-15 01:00:00
2017-01-15 01:00:00       |2017-01-14 21:00:04       |2017-01-14 21:00:05       |other stuff 09|2017-01-15 01:00:00
2017-01-15 01:00:00       |2017-01-14 21:00:05       |2017-01-14 22:00:01       |other stuff 10|2017-01-15 01:00:00
```

Happy playing ....

Marco the Sane